# How to code a spinner/circle with words in it in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to draw the following image in LaTeX! I appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: Hi Kate, welcome to the forum! Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi Tim! I'm not very familiar with LaTeX so I've only explored how to draw a circle and was lost after trying to add words and arrows in the circle.

Comment: what you want looks a lot like a pie chart. You could start from the examples provided [here](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Pie_Chart.html) and then add the arrow and the linebreaks after you get close to the right ratio/position of the two parts. Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

A seemingly overly complicate proposal which adjust the size of the circle to the texts and allows you to change `p` easily. (I did not see a rule for the direction of the arrow, so just hardcoded it.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={p=0.6;},nodes={circle,align=center}]
 \draw[thick] 
  (90+p*360/2:0.5)node[anchor=90+p*360/2+180] (n1)
    {Run\\  $p=\pgfmathparse{p}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}
  ({90+p*360+(1-p)*360/2}:0.5)node[anchor={90+p*360+(1-p)*360/2+180}] (n2)  
    {Hide\\  $1-p=\pgfmathparse{1-p}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}
  let \p1=(current bounding box.south west),
     \p2=(current bounding box.north east), 
     \n1={max(\x1,\y1,\x2,\y2)} in
  (0,0) circle[radius=\n1] (0,\n1) -- (0,0) node[fill,inner sep=1pt](b){}
  -- (90+p*360:\n1) (b) edge[-stealth] (-110:0.8*\n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is so helpful.